# WTL RedrawWindow parameterrs

Tags: c++, redraw, wtl

I'm new to the WTL C++. I'm really confused about the parameters that go into the RedrawWindows function especially for the flags. I'm just trying to update a window everytime I draw a line, but I don't exactly understand how

```
LRESULT  CDrawView::OnLButtonUp(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
{
    int xPos= GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
    int yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
    end.X = xPos;
    end.Y = yPos;

    Pen pen(Color(0, 0, 255));
    m_GraphicsImage.DrawLine(&pen, start.X, start.Y, end.X, end.Y);
```

I try to call RedrawWindow here,

```
RedrawWIndow(NULL,NULL, NULL, RDW_INTERNALPAINT)
```

So everytime I release the left mouse button the window gets updated. I'm having a really hard time understanding the parameters that go into the Redraw Function. I tried putting them all null minus the last one but Visual studio says that the function doesn't take 4 parameters even though I read the msdn microsoft...

Comment: Can you show us the call that you attempted and the error it gave?

Comment: RedrawWIndow(NULL,NULL, NULL, RDW_INTERNALPAINT)

Comment: i have tried all the different flags for the fourth parameter and visual studio tells me that RedrawWindow does not take 4 arguments

Comment: What you are trying to achieve exactly? I doubt you need `RedrawWindow` in first place.

Comment: As of now the user presses the left mouse button, and after he releases it a line is supposed to be drawn. This line is only showing up for me, when i maximize the window

Comment: Are you using WTL or MFC?

Comment: Why are you using RedrawWindow?  In general, all of your drawing should happen in response to WM_PAINT.  You probably should add the new line segment to a data structure, then call Invalidate, and the WM_PAINT handler should draw all the line segments in the data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling the global [`RedrawWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You're calling the member function [`CWindow::RedrawWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdf1xe8b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which takes 3 parameters.

```
BOOL RedrawWindow(
   LPCRECT lpRectUpdate = NULL,
   HRGN hRgnUpdate = NULL,
   UINT flags = RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW | RDW_ERASE 
); throw()
```

**Edit:**
These three parameters all have *default arguments*, meaning they don't need to be supplied an `RedrawWindow()` alone should work.

Comment: i tried that and Visual Studio says that "#define RDW_INVALIDATE and that argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type HRGN"

Comment: Is he using WTL or MFC? `CWnd::RedrawWindow` is an MFC function, and he claims to be using WTL.

Comment: i'm using WTL @NikBougalis

Comment: @NikBougalis I'm woindering the same, given the error `function doesn't take 4 parameters`. Editing with a second stab at it...

Comment: You *should* be able to just do `RedrawWindow();`

Comment: error C2660: 'ATL::CWindow::RedrawWindow' : function does not take 4 arguments... This is what i keep getting

Comment: Nik you are right. just doing RedrawWindow() without any parameters did the trick...i don't understand why because when i looked at the msdn it said it needed some arguments

Comment: You are looking at the Windows API version of the function on MSDN - which accepts a number of arguments. But you are not using the Windows API version of the function, you are using a framework (WTL) which has its own version of most Windows API functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way you should use and you are supposed to be using the API. Your mouse button handler should call `Invalidate()` or `InvalidateRect` with specific part of the window you are marking as needing an update. Your window will then receive `WM_PAINT` event at the first OS convenience and your paint handler would paint the line.

`RedrawWindow` might work out this time, however is likely to be a base of a next problem very soon because you are already on the wrong way.